# C# & ASP.NET MVC 5 : send email using smtp.gmail.com on GoDaddy hosting not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email using the SendEmail code in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I am using the `smtp.gmail.com` server on a GoDaddy hosting account. However, I am getting the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client certificate is invalid.

I have checked my email settings and I am sure that my password is correct. I have also enabled the "Allow less secure apps" setting. I have also checked the SMTP settings in the GoDaddy cPanel and they are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
public static bool SendMail(string mailFrom, string mailFromPass, string displayName, string mailTo, string mailCC, string strSubject, string strBody, string smtpAddress, int portNumber, bool enableSSL)
{
    string sMail = mailTo.Replace("\r\n", ";");
    string[] arrayMTo = sMail.Split(';');

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
         mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, displayName);

         for (int j = 0; j < arrayMTo.Length; j++)
             if (arrayMTo[j] != "")
                 mail.To.Add(arrayMTo[j]);

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailCC))
             mail.To.Add(mailCC);

         mail.Subject = strSubject;
         mail.Body = strBody;
         mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
         mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
         mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
         mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

         using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
         {
             smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
             smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
             smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailFrom, mailFromPass);
             smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        
             try
             {
                 smtp.Send(mail);
                 return true;
             }
             catch
             {
                 return false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The GoDaddy cPanel settings I am using are as follows:

- SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
- SMTP Port: 587
- SMTP Username: my_email@gmail.com
- SMTP Password: my_password

Can anyone help me?